# Simplify and speed up process for querying database for every day of month

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a feeling that this isn't the most effective way to go about obtaining and displaying this information, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere that directly applies to what I'm doing. I need to query the database for each day of the month and display that information. I need to display every day in the month even if there is no data.

The only way I know how to do this is to query the database for every day. I know querying the database too often slows down the page load time. Should I get the data for the entire month and search through the array instead?

The basic idea of what I am doing:

```
// DATES OF MONTH ARE IN AN ARRAY CALLED $dates
foreach($dates as $key => $date){
    $getdata = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `Data` WHERE section = $section AND type = $typeid AND `date` = $datecomp");
    $info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getcatdata);
    if(isset($info)){
        // Display info
    }
    else {
        // Display empty div
    }
}
```

Comment: Select dates in a range `date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate` then output it in any way you want

Comment: But how do I differentiate between the different dates? And what about the dates that don't have records?

Comment: Iterate over the same range in php

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're suggesting. If you had some sort of example to answer with maybe I would understand.

Comment: Ok. Let's imagine you don't have php and mysql, but have the data on the piece of paper. How would you put it on another piece of paper in the desired format?

Comment: I would look through the list and write down what I needed and cross if off when I was done.

Comment: Running queries in a loop is generally a bad idea. It is not always possible to avoid it, but you should try to make as few queries as possible. So, is there a reason that you cannot select everything (sorting it appropriately) and then loop through the result as you display it? Also, you never use the `foreach` variables (`$key` and `$date`). What is up with that?

Comment: That is why I'm here looking for a better way to do it. Also, if the query is based on a variable that changes with each trip through the loop then that query would have to be inside the loop. For instance, if the variable $section was also an array and this example was within that loop. And as I said, that is the basic idea of what I'm doing. Meaning it's general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a query, which will return you all records within the datarange.

Then in PHP scroll through dates and on each date check if you have any records within the DB query results.

if yes - show them
if not - show empty div

Without very much details the PHP would be like that:

```
$getdata = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `Data` WHERE section = $section AND type = $typeid AND `date` BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate");
$info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getcatdata);
$dbData = Array(); // this will be an assoc array with dates as keys
foreach($info as $row) {
    $dbData[$row["date"]] = $row;
}

$unixStartDate = strtotime($startDate);
$unixEndDate = strToTime($endDate);
for($i=$unixStartDate; $i<=$unixEndDate; $i=$i+60*60*24) {
    if(array_key_exists(date('Y-m-d', $i), $dbData)){
    // Display info of $dbData[date('Y-m-d', $i)]
    }
    else {
    // Display empty div
    }
}
```

Note: the code might be slightly different if your date field format is not yyyy-mm-dd.

So, as summary - you have one DB query. It will be faster.